# get_the_term_list() display in ul li and remove <a> tag

Tags: terms

I want to remove  tag in get_the_term_list()

```
<?php echo '<ul class="styles">';
echo get_the_term_list( $post->ID, 'portfolioType', '<li>', ',</li><li>', '</li>' );
echo '</ul>'; ?>
```

It's need to return

```
<ul>
<li>List one </li>
<li>List two </li>
</ul>
```

i tried with preg_replace() but not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php $terms = get_the_terms();
   echo '<ul class="styles">';
   foreach($terms as $term){
     echo "<li>".$term->name."</li>";
   }
  echo "</ul>";
?>
```